# Using custom Repository in Sylius Resource grid

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have generated a Grid with CRUD actions for my `Labellisation` entity on Sylius.
The grid is displayed well, but I would like to get associated elements too (the defaultAdresse of the -> customer of the -> current labellisation), so I need to use a custom repository method.

I tried to do this with this conf :

```
labellisation_grid:
    resource: |
        alias: grid.label
        criteria:
            valide: true
        except: ['create', 'delete', 'update']
        grid: public_labels
        templates: LabelBundle:public/Crud
    type: sylius.resource
    defaults:
        _sylius:
            repository:
                method: findAllValides
```

(adding all the `defaults` block), but I have an error because the method findAllValides is not defined. I do have a findAllValides method in my LabellisationRepository.
Debugging the `ResourcesResolver`, I saw in the `getResource` that the `$repository` passed to this function has a `customRepositoryClassName = LabelBundle\Repository\LabellisationRepository` (this path is the good one to my LabellisationRepository).

Is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and have not found anything yet ... :(